# Asp.net and compatibilityMode why is compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" working?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, 3des

I have a legacy asp.net app that I upgraded to 3DES encryption.   My dev machine off course worked fine , QA worked fine( worked fine as in no errors in encryption and decryption ) .  However when I deployed it to staging I could not get it to work.  The app started throwing a decryption errors.
After a lot of googling I found that I had to add  compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" to my web.config.

Can someone help me understand what is this ?  Why would my app have worked on other environments.  I know this works, but why I cannot understand?

Answer (score 5):

From the `compatibilityMode` I am going to assume that you are, in fact, talking about the `machinekey` element.

I'd also guess, because you haven't included the exception details you might be seeing something like

> When using  or the
> MachineKey.Protect and MachineKey.Unprotect APIs, the 'validation'
> attribute must be one of these values: SHA1, HMACSHA256, HMACSHA384,
> HMACSHA512, or alg:[KeyedHashAlgorithm].

Frankly, you should *not* be using 3DES. That's not an upgrade by any means. 3DES is broken crypto. The errors you are getting are likely trying to steer you away from using broken crypto, because the .NET team would like you to be safe. Using such old crypto, especially with webforms can expose you to remote code execution.

**Stop using 3DES.**

Unless you are in a webfarm stop using the machinekey element at all, let asp.net autogenerate a machine key for you, and default to what it considers safe.